# Change of variables in triple integration using polar coordinates

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable

The World Geodetic System (the international standard used by GPS devices) models the
Earth as an oblate spheroid described by the equation
$$x^2/a^2+y^2/a^2+z^2/b^2=1$$

where a ≈ 6378.1370 km is the equatorial radius, and b ≈ 6356.7523 km is the polar
radius. Use this information and a triple integral to calculate an estimate of the volume of
the Earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triple integral for the volume is

$$V=\int_{A(x,y)} \int_{-b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2-y^2/a^2}}^{b\sqrt{1-x^2/a^2-y^2/a^2}}dzdydx$$
$$=2b\int_{A(x,y)} \sqrt{1-x^2/a^2-y^2/a^2}dydx$$

In polar coordinates,

$$V= 2b\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a \sqrt{1-r^2/a^2}rdrd\theta=\frac43\pi ba^2$$

which is about 1.083$\times 10^{12}$km$^3$.

Comment: I have managed to do it by integrating 1 and adjusting the Jacobian to a^2br^2sin(phi) and I got the same answer so it should be correct